# Background image with textured edges not showing on all screen sizes. WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

We are redesigning our homepage. I am building it in Gutenberg along with [Spectra blocks](https://wpspectra.com/blocks/).

Some blocks have a background image and the background image has a textured (ripped paper look) edge.
[photo of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVAPW.png)

The problem is, this texture doesn't show on all desktop sizes. It shows on mobile and tablet and small desktops.

At about the 1500px screen-size mark, the edges become flat:
[photo of how it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym4De.png)

Since this is only happening on larger screens, I figured it could be related to the size of the image itself. As a test I have put in extra large photos (I know this wouldn't be great for website performance but just to see) I uploaded an image with the dimensions of 5625 by 8438 pixels, the website resized it to 2560 by 3840 pixel. I see now that is the maximum size...

And.. still the same result:
[still flat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I7aZ.png)
Flat and not textured.

I am not sure what to troubleshoot next... Thoughts?